# Significance Test for Linear Support Vector Machines

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, svm

As we know, after applying a linear regression model to a continuous data set we carry out a significance test to each parameter βi associated with the predictor variable xi to check whether the latter contributes to the explanation of the dependent variable yi.

H0:βi=0,
H1:βi≠0.

Can we apply the same procedure to a linear SVM classifier?

Comment: Have you read the comments to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/453566) question?

Comment: There's no need to copy and paste the content of another question to a new thread without any additional information.